# Java LinkedList split in half (Merge sort)

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list, mergesort

currently I am learning about merge sort with Linked List. I don't understand well how to  split the original ListNode in half.

I cannot understand clearly why `ListNode left = mergeSort(head);` isn't head entire original ListNode not only left half? and why method getMiddleNode only return slowptr?

as I assume, `ListNode left = mergeSort(head);` only contains left half but I want to understand how head is only become half.

Thank you!

Here is my code

```
class Solution {
  public ListNode mergeSort(ListNode head) {
    if(head == null || head.next == null){
      return head;
    }
    
    ListNode middle = getMiddleNode(head);
    
    ListNode left = mergeSort(head);
    ListNode right = mergeSort(middle);
    
    return merge(left, right);
  }
  
  ListNode getMiddleNode(ListNode head)
  {
    ListNode pre = null;
    ListNode slowptr = head;
    ListNode fastptr = head;
    
    while(fastptr != null || fastptr.next != null)
    {
      pre = slowptr;
      slowptr = slowptr.next;
      fastptr = fastptr.next.next;
    }
    
    pre.next = null;
    return slowptr;
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that a [bottom up merge sort for linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation_using_lists) avoids having to scan lists to split them. Instead a small (25 to 32) array of node references are used, where  array[i] is either null or points to a list of 2^i nodes.

Answer (score 1):

> I cannot understand clearly why ListNode left = mergeSort(head); isn't
> head entire original ListNode not only left half?

with `pre.next = null;` the following node of the node before the middle node is set to null, so there dosnt exist an link between first half of the linkedList (from head to pre, inklusiv) and the second half(from middle to end, inklusiv), so they have become two independent lists.

> and why method getMiddleNode only return slowptr?

because after the loop, slowptr is pointing to the node in the middle of the linkedList. slowptr and fastptr are initialised as head, and then both "walk" throug the list. But fastptr at double the speed of slowptr (`fastptr = fastptr.next.next;` instead of `slowptr = slowptr.next;`), so when fastptr is at the end, slowptr has done half the way <=> is in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

You can clearly understand why **ListNode left = mergeSort(head);** is contains only left part of the list, by printing **head** right after **getMiddleNode(head);**

The reason, is you're spliting the list into two halves in getMiddleNode(head) function. and When you are doing same thing over and over again by recursion, consecutively, you will get left half of the list, whose boundary is current middle, and exactly opposite for right half (i.e., right half of the list whose boundary is current middle to current-last-element).

For example, consider this one is your initial list, in which you want to apply merge sort.
11->8->3->35->4

after getMiddleNode(head), you will get two list like following:

11->8->3(left) and 35->4(right)

now if we call same function one more time we'll get:

11->8(left) and 3(right) [ for prev left part]

35 and 4 (for prev right part) [for prev right part]

now for prev right part base case found, we can sort/swap it,
likewise, same is true for right of prev left part, that is 3.

so till now, our list is: 3, 4, 35

if we apply same logic over left of prev left part(11->8), we will get:

11(left) and 8(right)

now base case found again for current list, so we can make them sort, and finally we will get,

3 4 8 11 35.

that's how legendary merge sort works.

Comment: Thank you! that make sense!